# ImportError: /tmp/_MEIpePG2T/PyQt5/sip.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_Unpack in create exe file using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, python-sip

I have a problem with converting my scripts into one exe file.
I used module PyQt5 and my custom modules.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem and create exe file?
It's important to mention that I have venv but I couldn't match its libs to my script so I added all of the files in site-packages of venv and I add this directory when I want to exe command :

```py
pyinstaller -p 'Controller:GUI_Implementor:Processor:Modules' --hidden-import PyQt5.sip --onefile -y  Run.py
```

Output when I execute (./Run):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project/Run.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/home/kimia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "Project/Controller/Handler.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/kimia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "Project/GUI_Implementor/Displayer.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: /tmp/_MEILeWbSZ/PyQt5/sip.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_Unpack
[5295] Failed to execute script Run
```

Here are my Modules and my main script Run.py
Project

```
__ Controller / Handelr.py
__ GUI_Implementor / Displayer.py
__ Processor / ...
__ Modules /...
__ Run.py
__ venv
```

all of the above is in my Project directory.

Comment: show the **complete** error message

Comment: I added complete error for you.
Thank You

Comment: As I have seen in several publications that the problem was solved using python>= 3.6

Comment: Yes, it works.Thank you so much